# Crontab and session locked

Tags: macos, screen-lock, cron

I would like to execute a script on my machine every five minutes, even when I am not in front of my mac OS X Yosemite. Therefore, I would like to lock my session and shut off the screen while the computer stays active. How can I do that.
I have tried with a crontab.

Let's say this is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
D=`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M`
echo "Hello" > "test_$D.txt"
```

and this is my crontab entry

```
*/5 * * * * /MyPath/script.sh > /MyPath/log
```

When I do this, and when I lock my session, or start the screen saver, the crontab doesn't execute, which mean that I need to keep my session and my screen open all day long. Is there a way to do what I want to do with a mac?

Comment: Cron jobs *should* execute even while the screen saver is running. Does the job execute correctly every 5 minutes while the computer is running?

Comment: Actually, whenever you write a cron job, test it by running it directly. It's a good practice, you'll be sure it works before actually putting it in a cron.

Answer (score 2):

Patrix got it right. I have made a mistake in my bash script, which caused error... Sorry for the post.

Comment: It's helpful if you post *what* your mistake was and what you did to *fix* it.  As it stands, this is more of a comment than an answer.